# Return a list of the odd indices using List.map

Tags: ocaml

If I have a list [1;2;3;4;5;6] and I want to return a list of the odd indices [2;4;6], could I do this with List.map and some function? I'm having difficulty figuring this out.

Comment: Since you want to *filter* the list you probably want to use `List.filter` or `List.filteri`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `List.map` does is return a function (call it `f` say) of each of the elements of the list. For each element `x` of the input list, it returns `f x` in the resulting list. Hence, the returned list is always the same length as the one it is passed.

Since you want a shorter list, you can't use `List.map`.

As @UnholySheep says, you could use `List.filteri`. It's specifically intended for returning only some of the elements of the list based on their position in the list.